# Why can't I print the contents from a Tensor object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to load a pandas dataframe into a Tensorflow dataset. Am I missing something such as an attribute for the Tensor object? Or could it be an import issue?

I've been trying to do this according to the following example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/pandas

I am not getting the expected output.

I was trying this more complex example before, which gave me similar results:
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns

Even when copying the first mentioned example exactly in the terminal it doesn't behave as shown.

Here is the code:

```py
URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(URL)

df['thal'] = pd.Categorical(df['thal'])
df['thal'] = df.thal.cat.codes

target = df.pop('target')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))

for feat, targ in dataset.take(5):
    print('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(feat, targ))
```

Expected output:

```
Features: [ 63.   1.   1. 145. 233.   1.   2. 150.   0.   2.3  3.   0.   2. ], Target: 0
Features: [ 67.   1.   4. 160. 286.   0.   2. 108.   1.   1.5  2.   3.   3. ], Target: 1
Features: [ 67.   1.   4. 120. 229.   0.   2. 129.   1.   2.6  2.   2.   4. ], Target: 0
Features: [ 37.   1.   3. 130. 250.   0.   0. 187.   0.   3.5  3.   0.   3. ], Target: 0
Features: [ 41.   0.   2. 130. 204.   0.   2. 172.   0.   1.4  1.   0.   3. ], Target: 0
```

Actual output:

```
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_2:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_2:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_3:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_3:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_4:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_4:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_5:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_5:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_6:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_6:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
Features: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_7:0", shape=(13,), dtype=float64), Target: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_7:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
...
```

Edit:
I tried adding after import:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

It's working now!

Comment: Can you try adding `tf.enable_eager_execution()` just after importing tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
tf.enable_eager_execution()

URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(URL)

df['thal'] = pd.Categorical(df['thal'])
df['thal'] = df.thal.cat.codes

target = df.pop('target')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))

for feat, targ in dataset.take(5):
    print('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(feat, targ))
```

Try it and let me know.